# Process of conversion of types inside selection and iteration statements in C++

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement, language-lawyer

According To C++ ISO:

> The value of a condition that is an initialized declaration in a
> statement other than a switch statement is the value of the declared
> variable contextually converted to bool (7.3). If that conversion is
> ill-formed, the program is ill-formed. The value of a condition that
> is an initialized declaration in a switch statement is the value of
> the declared variable if it has integral or enumeration type, or of
> that variable implicitly converted to integral or enumeration type
> otherwise. The value of a condition that is an expression is the value of the
> expression, contextually converted to bool for statements other than switch; if that conversion is ill-formed,
> the program is ill-formed.

The following quote comes from the section 7.3 said above:

> Certain language constructs require that an expression be converted to
> a Boolean value. An expression **e** appearing in such a context is said
> to be contextually converted to bool and is well-formed if and only if
> the declaration bool t(e); is well-formed, for some invented temporary
> variable t (9.4).

Based on these two, I got an idea that `switch-statement` not always conducts conversions if it has the appropriate type. Otherwise `if-statement` looks to always perform such conversion, even if I do something like `if (true){}`,I understood the `true` value would be converted. So, is it what happens? The code: `if(true){}` will convert `true` to boolean?(even true already being a boolean)

Comment: Any value can be converted to its own type.

Comment: So,  bool true is converted to bool,?

Comment: I don't understand. "_`if(true){}` will convert `true` to boolean?_" - what conversion would a `bool`, like `true`, need to become a `bool`?

Comment: In the quote it is said for `switch-statements` that the value of the condition is the value itself if it has enumeration or integral. Although, for `if-statements` the first quote doesn't say it, it says is converted. That was my interpretation

Comment: You are reading too much into this. This is just standartese for "we'll make the type fit, under certain conditions".

Comment: "An expression e appearing in such a context is *said to be* contextually converted to bool" (emphasis mine). It does not say that the expression *is* converted, it's an explanation of what the standardese phrase "contextually converted" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comments already discussed that you are misinterpreting the two paragraphs. I will focus on the second. The important message is the following:

There are certain contexts where values might implicitly undergo  converions even though the conversion is actually only possible explicitly.

Some code examples might help:

```
struct foo{
    explicit operator bool() {return true;}
};

int main()
{
   foo f;
   bool b(f);    // fine !
   bool c = f;   // error! no viable conversion from f to bool
                 // because foo::operator bool is explicit
}
```

A `foo` can be converted to a `bool` but the conversion operator is `explicit`. Hence `bool b(f)` (explicit conversion) is fine, while `bool c = f;` (implicit conversion) is not.

Now, there are certain contexts where...

> An expression e appearing in such a context is said to be contextually converted to bool and is well-formed if and only if the declaration bool t(e); is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable t (9.4).

This explains some special case of conversions. Such conversion happen implicitly, but are well-formed exactly when the explicit conversion would be well formed.

With out such "contextual conversion", this would be a compiler error:

```
 foo f;
 if (f) {}
```

However, because `f` is contextually convertible to `bool`, the code is ok. Without this special rule for contextual conversion one would have to write `if (bool(f))` because `foo::operator bool` is `explicit`.

In other words, the paragraph is not about `bool`s getting converted to `bool`, but rather it explains an exception from the usual implicit / explicit conversions, that are applied when necessary.